# Why can't I find any diamonds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge, minecraft-thaumcraft

I am having some trouble locating diamonds; I can find anything **but** diamonds. I'm not a new player, I understand the how and where to find diamonds, and I've never had trouble before. I've managed to find 2 in chests, but I don't think they are spawning underground.

Is Minecraft broken (preventing natural deposits of diamond from spawning)? Is something wrong with my version of Minecraft specifically? Does it have something to do with my installed mods? Or am I just having an unlucky run?

I'm running Minecraft v1.7.10, with Forge and Thaumcraft installed.

Comment: Some mods, like Thaumcraft, alter the world generation. However in my previous world with Thaumcraft 4 I found diamonds and was mining obsidian but I haven't found any in the new world I created when I added some Thaumcraft add-ons. My suggestion, just for debugging, is to find and download a texture pack which makes all blocks see though except for ores and in create mode see if you can find any diamonds, it may be your just been very, very unlucky since there's no reason that diamond blocks have to appear in cave networks.

Comment: For future reference Diamond tends to stay between level 12 and 5 being plentiful.

Comment: Are you sure you looked deep enough? Diamonds are only found at level 16 or below.

Answer (score 4):

According to Minecraft Wiki, there is an average of 3.097 diamond ore per chunk-sized area. I think you are just being unlucky.